# How to click button in MS Access using C# and Office Interop?

Tags: c#, ms-access, office-interop, office-automation, ribbonx

I am trying to automate some tasks in MS Access which are involving some button presses. Here are my best guesses so far, but I never find a way to finally execute a click...

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;

Application access = new Application();
access.OpenCurrentDatabase("SomeDatabaseName.accdb");
access.DoCmd.OpenForm("SomeFormName", AcFormView.acNormal);
access.DoCmd.GoToControl("SomeButtonName");
access.DoCmd... // I can go to the control, but how do I click it?
```

Or maybe there is another approach using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.CommandButton` instance?

```
var form = access.Forms["SomeFormName"];
foreach (var control in form.Controls)
{
    if (control is CommandButton button)
    {
        // I can get the CommandButton, but how do I execute the click procedure?
        string onClick = button.OnClick; // it's just this string: "[Event Procedure]"
    }
}

access.CloseCurrentDatabase();
access.Quit(AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone);
```

Is this possible using the MS Office Interop assemblies? Or are there any alternatives? Unfortunately, these interop assemblies are very poorly documented.

Comment: What does the button do when clicked? If it's calling a sub for example, why not call the sub directly?

Comment: @KostasK. I need a generic solution which works for any button. But yeah, I also tried to programatically retrieve the name of the OnClick-Sub of the button and execute it directly, but I also didn't find a solution for this approach. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You cannot get the button's click handler cause it's private to the form. The sub/function must be declared public inside a standard module. See this, it's in VBA but you can easily convert it to C#. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.run

Comment: @KostasK. So it is not possible to execute a button click via C#?

Comment: Just calling a public sub if you know it's name?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to click a button programmatically, since it's user input. SendKeys maybe, but I'm not very familiar with it (not sure if it's even possible in C#). Public sub/function in a standard module is the only way I know of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CommandBars.ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) method which executes the control identified by the `idMso` parameter. This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in `buttons`, `toggleButtons`, and `splitButtons`. On failure it returns `E_InvalidArg` for an invalid `idMso`, and `E_Fail` for controls that are not enabled or not visible. For example:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("Copy")
```

If you need to execute non-ribbon controls you may consider using Windows API functions or [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) for that.

Comment: I think this does only work with controls in the / a command bar. When I add `access.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("SomeButtonName");` to my code above, an ArgumentException is thrown: _"Value does not fall within the expected range."_

Comment: It works for the ribbon controls.

Comment: I need a solution which is applicable to form controls, like a button.

Comment: The post was updated to consider such cases.

Comment: I don't find any C# sample code for "Microsoft Active Accessibility". Do you have any reference for me?